# Jquery Datepicker returning Monday-Friday only

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

**What I'm trying to do:**
I'm trying to create a datepicker that when a date is selected it will return a date 2 days or 48 hours later, only during a work week (Monday-Friday) in another input field.

I found a tutorial [Here](http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2013/01/jquery-ui-datepicker-examples.html) That got me most of the way, except that when you pick a date that is on a Friday it returns Sunday, which wont work because it's not part of the work week.

**I would need it to return something like this:**
if Monday Return next Wednesday's date
if Tuesday Return next Thursday's date
if Wednesday Return next Friday's date
if Thursday Return next Monday's date
if Friday Return next Tuesday's date
if Saturday Return next Tuesday's date
if Sunday Return next Tuesday's date

**This is the code so far:**

```
<input id="datepicker" type="text">
<p id="dateoutput"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {

                var date = $.datepicker.parseDate(inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, dateText, inst.settings);
                var dateText1 = $.datepicker.formatDate("D, mm-dd-yy", date, inst.settings);
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + 2);
                var dateText2 = $.datepicker.formatDate("D, mm-dd-yy", date, inst.settings);
                $("#dateoutput").html(dateText2);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The other issue I have is getting the returned date to populate in another input field. (right now it's just populating a p tag).

Any Help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/mpoisel/LDaXa/

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: This becomes difficult if you want something that is also aware of public/bank holidays...

Comment: Actually I'm not really concerned with holidays right now.

Comment: sorry about that, I had to create a jsfiddle account.  Here's the [http://jsfiddle.net/mpoisel/LDaXa/](http://jsfiddle.net/mpoisel/LDaXa/)

Comment: @user2437336 do you want to be able to even click on Saturday/Sunday? or do you want them disabled?

Comment: disabling them would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would go about it...

- First, I would set option [`beforeShowDay`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) to [`$.datepicker.noWeekends`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-noWeekends)(since weekends are basically useless).
- Next, use [`onSelect`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) and, based on user's selection, use [`.getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate%2FgetDay).  If the date is Thursday (*4*) or Friday (*5*), make `addDays = 4`
   *4 days = (2 days + Saturday + Sunday)*.
- Finally, use [`$.datepicker.formatDate(format, date, settings)`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate) and you will be good to go!

Also, regarding issues with populating another `input`, make sure to use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

---

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/Qt6QB/

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends, //disables weekends
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            var date = new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay);
            var day = date.getDay();
            var addDays = 2;
            if(day === 4 || day === 5){
                addDays = 4;
            }

            var nextDate = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + addDays));

            //for p, use .html() or .text()
            $("#dateoutput1").html($.datepicker.formatDate('D, mm-dd-yy', nextDate)); 

            //for input, use .val()
            $("#dateoutput2").val($.datepicker.formatDate('D, mm-dd-yy', nextDate));
        }
    });
});
```

Let me know if you have any other questions! Happy coding!

---

**EDIT:**

Here is the new [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mpoisel/h2VdQ/) you provided.

To change the [`minDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) based on the day of the week, try doing something like this:

```
$(function () {
    var today = new Date(); //today's date
    var minDate;

    if(today.getDay() < 4){
         minDate = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() + 2));
    }else{
         minDate = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() + 4));
    }

    $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
        minDate: minDate,
        dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
    });
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/h2VdQ/4/

Comment: Actually I do have one more question.  Is there a way to conditionally set the minDate so that if it is Friday you won't be able to select Monday or Tuesday in the datepicker?

Comment: What is the `minDate` on other days? Do you have a demo I can see?

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/mpoisel/h2VdQ/.  I basically want A default minDate of +2 but if it's Thursday or Friday a minDate of +4

Comment: @Mike updated my answer, let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: I was testing it with a future date (a Friday 06-07-2013) and it breaks.